# Different versions of \theta

Tags: greek, letters

When I try to write `\theta`, the displayed symbol is different from the usual symbol (as shown in figure). It is not closed, rather looks more like `\vartheta`. How can I get the closed theta symbol?

[image]

The document setup is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\usepackage{bm}
%package for checked box and crossed box
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
```

Comment: Hello. See my (or @frougon's) edit for a way to format an example. We need an MWE, i.e., please remove the packages and definitions that are not relevant. Please include a document body, illustrating your problem. Using a more common document class, such as `article` might also help.

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! There is no `\theta` in your example - please include it (and any other code that is needed, such as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) to make the issue reproducible. However, as a guess from the preamble maybe `mathastext` has something to do with the appearance of the symbols.

Comment: The problem is `mathastext`: why are you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer by Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505024) uses the teletype font (lmtt) for the theta. There are some alternatives with other font styles.

Use the `basic` option for `mathastext`, which causes the package to only influence digits and Latin letters, resulting in the default math theta (but it limits the functionality of `mathastext`):

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[basic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
$0\degree \leq\theta\leq 180\degree$
\end{document}
```

[image: math italic theta]

Using the `symbolgreek` option, which uses the Symbol font for Greek:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[symbolgreek]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
$0\degree \leq\theta\leq 180\degree$
\end{document}
```

[image: symbol theta]

Redefining only `\theta` according to the default LaTeX definition, resulting in the default (math italic) theta (but it does not limit the functionality of `mathastext`):

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\mathchardef\theta="112
\begin{document}
$0\degree \leq\theta\leq 180\degree$
\end{document}
```

[image: math italic theta]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for filling the details. It works beautifully.

Comment: Your answer is the best (IMHO).

Answer (score 5):

Here, I think there is a solution using `\MTgreekfont{lmtt}\Mathastext`: this code is taken here http://jf.burnol.free.fr/showcase.html (there are many solutions) and I have put also the `italic` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[LGRgreek,italic]{mathastext}
\MTgreekfont{lmtt}\Mathastext
\begin{document}
$0^{\circ}\leq \theta \leq 180^{\circ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!